# Unable to Update bisnode-deviation on Bisnode Form of Coupa SIM

Tags: spring-boot, rest, coupa

I have to update SIM by **Easy_Form_response** (Bisnode) to change deviation to **YES**.
I tried following payload *with* and *without* **Subject**  but this does not help this way.

Header information:

> **Content-type**: XML and JSON **Accept**: XML and JSON

**Payload XML**

```
<easy-form-response>
    <subject>
        <custom-fields>     
            <bisnode-deviation>Yes</bisnode-deviation>
        </custom-fields>
    </subject>
</easy-form-response>
```

**PAYLOAD JSON**

```
{
    "id": :ID,
    "subject": {
        "id": ID,
        "custom-fields": {
            "bisnode-deviation": "yes"
        }
    }
}
```

End Point coupa

> PUT:
>   api/supplier_information/:SIM_ID/easy_form_responses/:EASY_FORM_RESPONSE_ID

and getting this response from Coupa

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
    <error>
        <![CDATA[An unknown error occured while creating/updating this record.]]>

    </error>
</errors>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You may get help from this URL. have a look at it.
https://success.coupa.com/Integrate/Technical_Documentation/API/Resources/Transactional/Easy_Form_Responses_API_(%2F%2Feasy_form_responses)#Actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be different scenarios in Coupa in terms of `SIM`, `Supplier`, `Invoice`, and all their other financial terms you should have to refer their documentation or contact email about your issue you are facing.

some of the their endpoints are:

> **PUT** -  **/api/users/:user_id/easy_form_responses/:id/add_approver**
> **add_approver**    Manually add an approver for an easy form response

You can further look at documentation for all their APIs.

[Easy form response doc](https://success.coupa.com/Integrate/Technical_Documentation/API/Resources/Transactional/Easy_Form_Responses_API_(%2F%2Feasy_form_responses)#Actions)